# Services user/login and system/connect

Tags: services

I would like to know the difference between user/login and system/connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

system/connect

> Returns the details of currently logged in user.

user/login

> Login a user for a new session

To login a user you will use user/login service call... Once user is logged in if you would like to pull logged in user details you will use system/connect service.. You can see above details in services module help section

[image]
[image]